# Why is permission denied in terminal when I tried to install sass using node.js

Tags: node.js, npm, sass

Why can't I install? Help! I followed this tutorial and it told me to install node.js and I did.

```
karenchan:~ karenchan$ npm install -g sass
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/karenchan/.npm/_logs/2020-07-30T20_33_04_760Z-debug.log
karenchan:~ karenchan$ npm install -g sass
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/karenchan/.npm/_logs/2020-07-30T20_44_30_523Z-debug.log
karenchan:~ karenchan$
```

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151018/npm-throws-error-without-sudo

Comment: try 'sudo npm install -g sass' I believe you need to have elevated privileges to install globally (-g)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
```

Two solutions:

1. Install globally as "root", using [sudo](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo)

   ```
   sudo npm install -g sass
   ```
2. Install locally (so "permissions" shouldn't be an issue):

   ```
   cd <<my project>>
   npm install sass
   ```

FYI, other options might include:

- Edit your project's [package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install)
- Install and use [NVM](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)

Here's a good tutorial on the latter:

[Installing Node.js Tutorial: Using nvm, Tierney Cyren](https://nodesource.com/blog/installing-node-js-tutorial-using-nvm-on-mac-os-x-and-ubuntu/)

Comment: i tried your second method and the word "password" showed up with an icon, what does that mean? And I can't type anything afterwards

Comment: YAYY IT WORKED THANK YOU SO MUCH